# How to test "intermediate" method/layer

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, xunit

I have a method, that is basically just called from the controller and passes on the call to a repository, then returns the response from the repository to the controller. Don't know if "intermediate" method/layer is the right term, but you get the point. E.g.:

```
public List<Car> GetCars()
{
    List<Car> cars = _findCars.Find();
    return cars;
}
```

How do you make a useful test out of this? Maybe integration/system path test? And can you test it alone somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#:%7E:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20dependency%20injection,object%20is%20called%20a%20service.) library (like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)),
you can inject `_findCars` to a mock.

Than you can test only this layer of function when you control the "database" label and make asserts against the response of your function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I should have included that the project is .NET Core and I use the dependency injection container with it (so no Ninject). But it sounds like that it doesn't make sense to test this layer in isolation, since you - as you say - have to "control the database"? So it would be some sort of integration test? Thanks for the pointer

Comment: You can add **unit test** to check only this layer.